# In French, how do you say "brain-meltingly difficult"?

Tags: expressions, formulation-idiomatique

We were having a conversation in English, and someone passed some remark about the mind-numbingly steep learning curve involved in mastering the Arabic language:

> I constantly thought my **brain** was going to **melt**. (hyperbolically)

I was wondering how I would express in French what she said, and I'd probably say something like:

> L'arabe me faisait toujours me creuser la tête comme une folle ! À tel point que mon cerveau était à deux doigts d'en fondre...

Is it better to use "méninges" than "tête/cerveau"?

How do French speakers commonly express this idea? No need to stick to a literal translation; something that springs to mind in the flow of conversation.

Comment: D'habitude en français, quand quelque chose est utilisé au point de surchauffer, ça ne fond pas, ça fume.

Answer (score 4):

To express something difficult for someone to understand I sometime use the sentence which means *thinking a lot about something*.

> Se faire des noeuds au cerveau en étudiant l'arabe

The same idea can be conveyed this way too :

> Se prendre la tête en étudiant l'arabe

With the sentence *se creuser les méninges* you get the idea, but the meaning is not pejorative

Comment: nice ways to translate it. however, the version "se prendre la tête" shows that it is not only difficult, but also painfully annoying on top of it. a bit pejorative in the meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion :
*A apprendre l'arabe plusieurs heures par jour, j'avais **le cerveau en fusion**.*

Answer (score 2):

It is a little too strong and colloquial, but an expression that comes to mind is:

> *péter les plombs* (to freak)

Otherwise, you might say:

> *avoir le cerveau en surchauffe*

*Méninges* is old fashioned and *fondre* isn't very idiomatic when applied to the brain.

Here is how I would arrange your sentence:

> Apprendre l'arabe m'obligeait à me creuser la tête comme une folle ! Mon cerveau n'était pas loin de la surchauffe...

Comment: How would you weave these expressions into a sentence in this Arabic context?

Comment: Answer updated with a suggestion

Comment: I see. If "cerveau" and "fondre" don't go so well with each other, what's your take on "exploser" or "craquer" apart from "surchauffer": "mon cerveau était à deux doigts d'en **exploser** / **craquer**"?

Comment: *Mon cerveau était à deux doigts d'exploser* would be fine. OTOH, *craquer* apply more to people than their brain so that would be *j'étais à deux doigts de craquer* which is close to *j'étais à deux doigts de péter les plombs*..

Answer (score 2):

Inspiré par une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53861), un peu différent, mais au lieu de qualifier le niveau de difficulté ou d'évoquer métaphoriquement la réalisation d'un résultat, simplement l'énoncer familièrement :

> À chaque fois que j'étudiais l'arabe j'avais le cerveau [*en
> compote*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/compote/17630) (meurtri, détruit).

Ou évoquer la folie :

> Étudier l'arabe, c'est à [*s'arracher les cheveux*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/arracher/5325).